# PostgreSQL - pgAdmin - path to database

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am new to PostgreSQL and I can not found info about this. I am using pgAdmin III and my databse files are kept in instalation directory of PostgreSQL. So far so good. But now, I need to create huge DB, that is out of my HDD capacity. So I create RAID and want to move this single DB to this location. How can I specify path for single database to be somewhere else?

I dont want other on the same disk, since I have them on fast SSDs. The big one will be only for some data mining and I will remove it afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look a `tablespaces`. You can keep the main and small parts of the database in the SSD drives and migrate the bigger tables to the tablespaces in your other drive.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/manage-ag-tablespaces.html

In alternative the whole database can be put into the tablespace by setting the `default tablespace` parameter.